# Run a local LaTeX service

Tags: web-services, tinymce, latex

How do I run a local LaTeX service which sends a GIF/PNG image back? Maybe like [this](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C!x%3D%5Cfrac%7B-b%5Cpm%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2-4ac%7D%7D%7B2a%7D.gif). I know there are lots of web services. But our clients/servers do not have internet access. I have looked at https://github.com/scribtex/clsi written in ruby but it replies a XML with a link instead of the image (I need to pass LaTeX in the request URL in img tag [I'm using TinyMCE editor]).

EDIT: (More specific question) I want to have a decent LaTeX editor in TinyMCE like [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce/install.php) and want the image tags to have a src pointing to a local web service which generates the required images according to the LaTeX in the URL. This would make the text cross application compatible across various local sites.

Comment: do you want to show mathematical formulaes in the editor?

Comment: yes. so that its easy for people who do not know LaTeX to input equations. Maybe like [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce/install.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might point you into the right direction: http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2013/02/22/latex-build-server/ .

In case you want to show mathematcal formulas in the editor only, you don't need a LaTeX server. You may use the MathML notation. MathML is a standart implemented by HTML5 (Firefox, Opera and Chrome (and IE10, IE9 with AddOn) support it). To make it work you will have to add the MathML tags to the tinymce configuration parameters valid_elements and valid_children.

Here are some helpfull links to get you started:

- http://www.mozilla.org/projects/mathml/start.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML
- http://www.w3.org/Math/

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I want to have a decent LaTeX editor in TinyMCE like [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce/install.php) and want the image tags to have a src pointing to a local web service which generates the required images according to the LaTeX in the URL. This would make the text cross application compatible across various local sites.

Comment: no. It calls an external service [http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum%20x](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum%20x). We have no internet on our clients/servers.

Comment: well, then you wil have to set up your own latex build server. i hope the first link i posted is helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness in case someone is having a similar issue:

I'm one of the authors of [LaTeX Render Server](https://github.com/vsfexperts/LaTeX). We did have similar issues and created this project as a result. Basically, the service is offering a REST endpoint, which will accept raw latex code and return a rendered pdf as a result. The url is immutable, so it could be referenced in some other document. This service is meant to be used as a microservice in some intranet environment. There's no authentication, which could be addressed by using a reverse proxy in front of it (recommended to address loadbalancing/failover).